# Why does select() keep failing with EINTR errno?

Tags: c++, select, infinite-loop, eintr

I have a C++ application that includes this function:

```
int
mySelect(const int fdMaxPlus1,
         fd_set *readFDset,
         fd_set *writeFDset,
         struct timeval *timeout)
{
 retry:
  const int selectReturn
    = ::select(fdMaxPlus1, readFDset, writeFDset, NULL, timeout);

  if (selectReturn < 0 && EINTR == errno) {
    // Interrupted system call, such as for profiling signal, try again.
    goto retry;
  }

  return selectReturn;
}
```

Normally, this code work just fine, however, in one instance, I saw it get into an infinite loop where `select()` keeps failing with the `EINTR` `errno` code.  In this case, the caller had set the timeout to zero seconds and zero microseconds, meaning don't wait and return the `select()` result immediately.  I thought that `EINTR` only occurs when a signal handler occurred, why would I keep getting a signal handler over and over again (for over 12 hours)? This is Centos 5.  Once I put this into the debugger to see what was happening, the code returned without EINTR after a couple iterations. Note that the fd being checked is a socket.

I could add a retry limit to the above code, but I'd like to understand what is going on first.

Comment: Are you on Linux? Have you tried looking at [`explain_errno_select`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/explain_select)?

Comment: Have you done anything fancy regarding signals/signal handlers anywhere in the code ?  If you can reproduce it, how does the output look like if you attach the `strace` tool (use strace -p pid_of_your_program)

Comment: You should really look into the strace of your application for spammed signals. Maybe there's a third party library spamming SIGALRM (or something similarly subtle) for some reason you don't know or expect.

Comment: @nos Thus far it is not reproducible, so I'm going to add a limit on retries.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why you got this `EINTR`? I am getting the same issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456803/poll2-on-result-of-pipe2-is-mutating-fd

Comment: @Noitidart No, I just added code to handle the `EINTR` by counting the retries and after several thousand, inserting a 1000 uSec sleep between tries, and then finally after several thousand more throwing an error to let the higher level code reconnect as an alternate means of recovery.

Comment: Thanks very much for sharing that input!

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) may modify the *timeout* argument (passed by address). So you should copy it after the call.

```
retry:
struct timeout timeoutcopy = timeout;
const int selectReturn
  = ::select(fdMaxPlus1, readFDset, writeFDset, NULL, &timeoutcopy);
```

(in your code, your `timeout` is probably zero or very small after a few or even the first iterations)

BTW, I suggest rather using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) instead of `select` (since `poll` is is more C10K problem friendly)

BTW, `EINTR` happens on any signal (see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)), even without a registered signal handler.

You might use `strace` to understand the overall behavior of your program.

Comment: How does this cause the `EINTR` behavior that he's seeing?

Comment: But I don't want the clock to start over again, hence I let Linux modify the timeout to reflect time already waited, however, in this case, the timeout was zero seconds.

Comment: In this case, caller set timeout to zero to begin with.