# poll(2) on read fd of pipe(2) and fd of inotify_init() is resulting in endless EINTR

Tags: linux, pipe, jsctypes

### Update

Possible bug in Firefox - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1288293

### Old Post

I am writing a inotify file watcher.

My main thread first creates a pipe with `pipe` and then creates a polling thread, and sends this thread the read `fd` of the pipe.

```
int mypipe[2];
rez = pipe(mypipe)
if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int mypipe_fd = mypipe[0];
```

My polling thread then starts an infinite poll by watching the inotify `inotify_fd` and the pipe `mypipe_fd` with `poll` like this:

```
 int inotify_fd = inotify_init1(0);
 if (inotify_fd == -1) {
     exit('inotify init failed');
 }

 // IN_ALL_EVENTS = IN_ACCESS | IN_MODIFY | IN_ATTRIB | CONST.IN_CLOSE_WRITE | IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE | IN_OPEN | IN_MOVED_FROM | IN_MOVED_TO | IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE | IN_DELETE_SELF | IN_MOVE_SELF
 if (inotify_add_watch(inotify_fd, path_to_desktop, IN_ALL_EVENTS) == -1) {
    exit('add watch failed');
 }
 int mypipe_fd = BLAH; // this the read end of the pipe generated on the main thread

 pollfd fds[2];
 fds[0].fd = mypipe_fd;
 fds[1].fd = inotify_fd;
 fds[0].events = POLLIN;
 fds[1].events = POLLIN;

 if (poll(fds, 2, -1) == -1) {
     exit(errno);
 }
```

This exits as `poll` gives `-1` and `errno` of `4` endlessly. Same situation with `select` with either of the `fd`'s or both.

I did more tests. Even doing just `read(mypipe_fd, .., ..)` or `read(inotify_fd, .., ..)` continuously gives me `EINTR` as well. Mind boggling! Does anyone know what can be causing this? This behavior is seen on Ubuntu 14.01 and OpenSUSE 42.1 (the ones i tested on).

Comment: Is this C or Python? You mention ctypes so I assume the latter, but you're using semicolons everywhere... please post *actual*, verifiable code.

Comment: Haha this is javascript, js-ctypes. I found a typo and fixed it, in my code, but now the `EINTR` problem is in my `poll`, it changes my question. **embarassed**, will fix up question.

Comment: Then please tag it as Javascript, and not C.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It's a C question though, the javascript people have no idea what is going on above, I tried to abstract away the javascript.

Comment: There isn't a line of C code here. Just because the APIs you refer to are usually called from C code doesn't mean this is C. I am a C guy, and this `console.log('fds:', fds);` is *not* C. You might re-write the code in actual C as a test.

Comment: Also, is this being done in a loop? If so, it makes no sense to omit the loop from the code you've shown. Many errors involving select  or poll are because of a mistake in the loop.

Comment: Thanks @JonathonReinhart I actually don't know C very well, just enough to port it to javscript. I'll edit the code. My question is now `EINTR` on `poll`, (and on `select`). It's not running in a loop, its a single shot.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I edited it, is this ok now please?

Comment: I think you need a [mcve]. This is too vague to diagnose. And you have not posted valid C code. If you're asking about js-ctypes, then you should post a complete example in JavaScript and tag it as such. You're just not going to get the help you want with what you have here.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try to update the code with more example. This is a question about `select` and `poll(2)` and `pipe(2)` API giving me `EINTR`, the javascript people and js-ctypes (its just me in that section) will have no idea. :( I wanted to tag this with `libc` but it's not a tag.

Comment: It's just hard to test this out when you don't have any valid code to test. `EINTR` could be returned for a huge number of reasons, all depending on what exactly the file descriptors you have refer to.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try to show more code I'm so confused about this error for 2 days now.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I converted the code to C code how does it look? The `pipe(2)` call is done in thread #1 and the `poll(2)`/`select(3)` are done in thread #2. The `poll` is watching the read end of the pipe generated by `pipe(2)` and also the pipe generated by `inotify_init(0)`

Comment: Do you have any signals blocked? Im sorry, but this is why a [mcve] is requested. Because little code snippets like this often don't exhibit the problem you're seeing in the full app - it's somewhere else. Please, for your own good and ours, *create an MCVE*. If you make a little toy program with 2 threads that just read/write a pipe, you won't get EINTR. Keep adding the other pieces until you get the error. Narrow it down.

Comment: @Noitidart, your code looks bad :) 1) it still has compilation errors 2) it's not complete example that reproduces the problem. The question is interesting, but it's not clear how one can reproduce it. You could start your example with this: http://pastebin.com/xKFmdneC

Comment: Thanks very much @gavv! I will base my example on that. One thing though I am doing is I have two threads, I have no idea how to spawn threads in C, I do this in js-ctypes so its like a WebWorker but meant for native calls. I really appreciate this base! I will work on it!

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I'll keep trying, thanks for that. I don't know how to compile C though. I don't know if any signals blocked, I don't work with any signals, I didn't expect this, I only learned of signals when I saw I was getting `EINTR`. I really appreciate you and everyone else sticking through with me on this.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Oh wow. So the problem is that I am doing this from a spawned WebWorker in a Firefox addon and there was something in this list of changesets - https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/pushloghtml?fromchange=a6f7a33731bc&tochange=a35163f83d22 - that causes this bug. Firefox build `40.0a1 - 2015-04-16` is the first one where this doesnt work. It used to work fine in build `40.0a1 - 2015-04-15` and earlier. I filed a bug - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1288293

Comment: Nice job narrowing that down. Yes, running low-level C code in a very complex environment like a Web browser is bound to bring out issues like this. Hopefully the Firefox guys will be able to help you get this figured out.

Comment: As for this question, it's not particularly useful for future readers as-is. Perhaps if you edited the question, and kept it focused on js-ctypes and firefox, someone else struggling with a similar issue will be directed to your bug. You can even answer the question yourself with "this is a known bug with Firefox - see xxx".

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Understood. Will edit and retag this right away.